# Proving Logarithmic identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Today, I read these two new Logarithmic identity $\displaystyle$ $$a^{\log_a m} = m $$ $$\log_{a^q}{m^p} = \frac{p}{q} \log_a m$$ Both of them seems new to me,so even after solving some problems (directly) based on thesm I haven't fully understood how they holds good,Could anybody show me how to prove them ?

Comment: You know that $y = \log_b x \iff b^y = x$, right?

Comment: To restate Djaian's hint: the logarithm and exponential are inverses of each other.

Comment: Ok.That is for the first one I got it now ;) how about the second one ?

Comment: For the second identity: you're aware of the "change-of-base" formula, yes?

Comment: Edit to $a^{\log_am}=m$

Comment: @JM:Do you mean $\log_a m = \log_b m \cdot log_a b$ where b is any real $\gt 1$?

Comment: I understood you meant the alternate form of it ... that is the division with base `e`.

Comment: Not really: the thing is that you can change one logarithm into another, and that's regardless of what your starting and ending bases you have.

Comment: Hm.that's the rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just so this doesn't remain unanswered:

1. This is a statement of the fact that the functions $a^x$ and $\log_a\;x$ are inverses of each other; thus, $\log_a\;a^x=a^{\log_a\;x}=x$
2. Letting c be a positive real number not equal to one:

$\log_{a^q}\;m^p=\frac{\log_c\;m^p}{\log_c\;a^q}=\frac{p\;\log_c\;m}{q\;\log_c\;a}=\frac{p}{q}\log_a\;m$