# Simplifying this expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to simplify this?

$\displaystyle\frac{n^{\log m}}{m^{\log n}}$

Comment: Try rewriting each base.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How $a^{\log_b x} = x^{\log_b a}$ ?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10866/how-a-log-b-x-x-log-b-a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $x = a^{\log_a x}$

So we find that $n^{\log m} = e^{\log (n^{\log m})} = e^{\log m \log n}$

Similarly, we find that $m^{\log n} = e^{\log (m^{\log n})} = e^{\log n \log m}$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Apply $\log$ to the whole thing and use the quotient and powers rules for $\log$.  You should get a very simple result, which you can exponentiate to find your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $n^{\log m} = m^{\log n}$.

Comment: I laughed at this.

Comment: Sorry I stated the wrong question. It should had been "How to prove that those expressions are equal" +1

Comment: @Wilbert Barrera: To prove that, you can apply $\log$ to both sides, and use the fact that $\log$ is one-to-one.