# Problems simplifying logarithmic expressions

Tags: logarithms

I learned all the scripts provided, yet I simply cannot find a way to simplify the following equations:

---

$$4^{log_{2}9}$$
What I've thought so far: 9 may be written as $3^2$, so maybe we could do something with the base $log_2$, but therefore it would have to be $2^3$, not the other way round - cannot think of any other approach.

**EDIT:** See [How $a^{\log_b x} = x^{\log_b a}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10866/how-a-log-b-x-x-log-b-a) top answer (basically it explains how to transform $a^{\log_b(x)}$ to $x^{\log_b(a)}$)

---

$$8^{\frac{1}{3}log_{6}4}$$
What I've done so far: $8^{1/3}=2 \Rightarrow 8^{\frac{1}{3}log_{6}4} = 2^{log_{6}4}$ - but I have no idea how to simplify this term. (Maybe something with $4=2^2$ and $6=3*2$ and do something with the $2$s, but I don't know of any rule that allows you to "split" bases)

**EDIT:** turned out to be a typo, it should have read like this $8^{\frac{1}{3}log_{2}4}$ which basically is $2^2 = 4$

---

$$e^{\frac{1}{2}log9}$$
No idea what to do here. (Maybe try to "bring down" the natural logarithm, but how?)

**EDIT:** 
\begin{align*}
e^{\frac{1}{2}log9} &= 9^{\frac{1}{2}log9\ log_{9}e} \\\
&= 9^{\frac{1}{2}\frac{log_{9}9}{log_{9}e}log_{9}e} \\\
&= 3
\end{align*}
In words: change base, then change base in the exponent and cancel (can you put it like that in English?) so that only 3 remains.

---

$$b^{4log_{b}x}$$
Same like above - try to bring down the logarithm with the base $b$.

**EDIT:** (In thoughts) isolate the $log$, so that $b^{log_{b}x}$ remains $\Rightarrow$ this is $x$ $\Rightarrow$ the final result should be $x^4.

---

$$e^{3log\ 8x}$$
Same here with natural logarithm again.

**EDIT:** Same like the previous example, final result should be $(8x)^3$.

---

To prevent any misunderstandings: **I'm not asking for solutions or step-by-step-instructions, just want to know** if I'm heading in the right direction and **if there's any rule/approach I overlooked which can be applied here**. (Sadly we didn't do much logarithm-related stuff in school and at university it's considered to be foreknowledge, so they don't explain it any more)

Answer (score 3):

**A start:** $4=2^2$ and therefore $4^x=(2^2)^x=2^{2x}$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) Any way to further simplify $2log_{2}3^2$?

Comment: Yes, two ways. $2\log_a x=\log_a x^2$. Or better (I think) $2^{2\log_2 9}=2^{(\log_2 9)(2)}=(2^{\log_2 9})^2$. We are using $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$.

Comment: Ahh, god I should have thought of that... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

There is [a simpler way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854588/name-for-a-logarithm-identity-property?rq=1)

\begin{align}\large n^{\log_bx} = x^{\log_bn}\end{align}
Now we have for this question,
\begin{align}\large 4^{\log_29} = 9^{\log_24}\end{align}
As the OP is not asking for solution, please proceed from here.