# Name for a Logarithm Identity/Property

Tags: logarithms

I came across a neat logarithm fact today:

$\large n^{\log_bx} = x^{\log_bn}$

One simple proof is:

> $\large \log_bx\cdot \log_bn=\log_bx\cdot \log_bn$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_bx^{log_bn}=log_bn^{log_bx}$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow x^{\log_bn}=n^{\log_bx}$

So you can swap the base with part of the exponent. Does this property have a name? What is the intuition? The other log properties are very intuitive to me, but not this one.  Is it more easily derived from the usual four logarithm properties?

Comment: The point is that $a^{\log b} = e^{\log a \log b}$. I don't think this really has a name; it doesn't come up very often in my experience.

Comment: Oh, that's neat.  Sure I've never noticed it before...but keeping in mind that when you have a logarithm in the exponent, you may be able to swap log parameter with base of exponent is neat.

Comment: This is pretty neat. I thought it might be in my short note *Harmonious logarithm identities* in **Mathematical Gazette** [volume 93 number 526 (March 2009), pp. 95-97], of which an overview is given [here](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6470549), but it's not.

Comment: This also follows immediately from the facts that (1) $n=x^{\log_x n}$ and (2) $\log_x n = \log_b n \log_b x$.

Comment: EDIT: Of course, that's supposed to be $\log_b n / \log_b x$. Can't edit the comment now, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come across the same property and struggled to grasp the intuition until I try different numbers for n and x for in your equation.

$$n^{\log_bx} = x^{\log_bn}$$

Let's think about *n=2, x=8* and assume *b=10* and then try to generalize the concept.

$$2^{\log_{10}8} = 8^{\log_{10}2}$$
$$2^{\log_{10}2^3} = 2^{3\log_{10}2}$$
$$2^{3\log_{10}2} = 2^{3\log_{10}2}$$

So we can start to think with $n=x^k$ and it always results as following while log base doesn't matter except being the same:

$$n^{\log_bx} = x^{\log_bn} $$
 $$x^{k\log_bx} = x^{\log_bx^k} $$
 $$ x^{k\log_bx} = x^{k\log_bx} $$

Answer (score 0):

$$
n^{\log_b x}=b^{\log_bn\cdot\log_bx}=\dots
$$