# Tricky logarithmic question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have been asked to find $x$ satisfying the equation $$4^{(\log x)+1}-6^{\log x}-2\times3^{(\log x^2)+2}=0.$$

I am totally clueless how to solve this, so any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Take each side of the equation and raise 10 to that power.

Comment: Hint: the answer is $x=1/100$.

Comment: Are those $\log_{10} (x + 1) $ or $(\log_{10} x)+1$.  That will make a *huge* difference.

Comment: $\log_{10} (x + 1) $

Comment: Considering Greg Martins hint and Donald Splutterwit's deleted answer, I'm almost *certain* it must be $(\log_{10} x)+1$.  I see almost no way to solve other than graphing otherwise.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it closer to what it should have been in the first place, which is a faithful reproduction of the equation from the original image (without inserting extra parentheses), but formatted in MathJax. Inserting or not inserting parentheses makes a big difference in how the equation would be interpreted.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but note that $a^{\log_{10}c} = a^{\frac{\log_{a}c}{\log_{a}10}} = \left(a^{\log_a c}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_{a}10}} = c^{\frac{1}{\log_{a}10}} = c^{\log_{10}a},$ or more generally, $a^{\log_{b}c} = c^{\log_{b}a},$ which is a neat identity that I don't think I've come across before.

Comment: $\log(x^2)+2$ or $\log(x^2+2)$??

Comment: Sorry, I misguided everyone....this is the Q

Comment: Apparently I **HAVE** come across this neat identity before --- see [Name for a Logarithm Identity/Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854588/name-for-a-logarithm-identity-property).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get $x = \frac{1}{100}$ for your latest version (posted around midnight CST), and substitution into your equation shows that $\frac{1}{100}$ is a solution. My solution in great detail is given below. However, I suspect there is probably a quicker way to solve this equation than going through all the algebraic contortions I went through.

> *(ADDED ABOUT AN HOUR LATER)* Glancing over what I did suggested to me a quicker way, which I'll outline in this paragraph and leave my original solution alone. Letting $u = \log_{10}x,$ the equation becomes $4^{u+1} - 6^u - 18\cdot 9^u = 0.$ Some rewriting leads to $4\cdot \left(2^u\right)^2 - 2^u \cdot 3^u - 18 \cdot \left(3^u\right)^2 = 0,$ and this factors as $\left(2^u + 2\cdot 3^u\right)\left(4\cdot 2^u - 9 \cdot 3^u\right) = 0,$ which is now easy to solve for $u$ (same way I do near the end below), and now use $x = 10^{u}.$

In what follows, keep in mind that $x > 0$ holds, since otherwise two of the logarithms in the original equation are not defined. This will be used in at least two places, one being for the identity $\log_{10} x^2 = 2\log_{10}x$ and the other near the end when asserting that $x^{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} = -2$ has no solution.

$$ 4^{(\log_{10} x) + 1} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 2 \times 3^{(\log_{10} x^2) + 2} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4^{\log_{10} x}\times 4^1 \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 2 \times 3^{(\log_{10} x^2)} \times 3^2 \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4 \times 4^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 18 \times 3^{(\log_{10} x^2)} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4 \times 4^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 18 \times 3^{(2\log_{10} x)} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4 \times 4^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 18 \times \left(3^2\right)^{\log_{10} x} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4 \times 4^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log_{10} x} \;\; - \;\; 18 \times 9^{\log_{10} x} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

We now make use of the identity

$$a^{\log_{10}c} = c^{\log_{10}a},$$

which I mentioned in a comment and which can be justified as follows: $a^{\log_{10}c} = a^{\frac{\log_a c}{\log_a {10}}}$ (in the exponent, change base-$10$ logarithm to base-$a$ logarithms) **AND** $ a^{\frac{\log_a c}{\log_a {10}}} = \left( a^{\log_a c}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_a {10}}}$ (use the identity $a^{VW} = \left(a^V\right)^W)$ **AND** $\left( a^{\log_a c}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_a {10}}} = c^{\frac{1}{\log_a {10}}}$ (use the identity $a^{\log_a c} = c)$ **AND** $c^{\frac{1}{\log_a {10}}} = c^{\log_{10} a}$ (use the identity $\log_b a = \frac{1}{\log_a b}).$

Applying this identity gives

$$ 4 x^{\log_{10} 4} \;\; - \;\; x^{\log_{10} 6} \;\; - \;\; 18 x^{\log_{10} 9} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

Using $\; \log_{10} 4 = \log_{10} 2^2 = 2\log_{10} 2 \; $ **AND** $\; \log_{10} 6 = \log_{10} {(2 \cdot 3)} = \log_{10} 2 + \log_{10} 3 \;$ **AND** $\; \log_{10} 9 = \log_{10} {(3^2)} = 2 \log_{10} 3, \;$ we get

$$ 4 x^{2\log_{10} 2} \;\; - \;\; x^{\log_{10} 2 + \log_{10} 3} \;\; - \;\; 18 x^{2\log_{10} 3} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

$$ 4 \left(x^{\log_{10} 2}\right)^2 \;\; - \;\; x^{\log_{10} 2} \cdot x^{\log_{10} 3} \;\; - \;\; 18 \left(x^{\log_{10} 3}\right)^2 \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

Letting $\;A = x^{\log_{10} 2}\;$ and $\;B = x^{\log_{10} 3},\;$ this last equation becomes

$$4A^2 \; - \; AB \; - \; 18B^2 $$

The left side can be factored:

$$(A + 2B)(4A - 9B) \; = \; 0$$

Therefore, $\; A = -2B\;$ and $\;4A = 9B,\;$ which gives

$$ x^{\log_{10} 2} = -2x^{\log_{10} 3} \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;  4x^{\log_{10} 2} = 9x^{\log_{10} 3}  $$

Dividing both sides of each equation by $x^{\log_{10} 3}$ gives

$$ \frac{x^{\log_{10} 2}}{x^{\log_{10} 3}} = -2 \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;  
\frac{4x^{\log_{10} 2}}{x^{\log_{10} 3}} = 9 $$

$$ x^{\log_{10} 2 - \log_{10} 3} = -2 \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;  4x^{\log_{10} 2 - \log_{10} 3} = 9  $$

$$ x^{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} = -2 \;\;\;\; \text{and} \;\;\;\;  4x^{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} = 9  $$

Since $x > 0$ (see very beginning above), the left equation has no solution. To solve the right equation, we first divide both sides by 4 and then we raise both sides to the $\frac{1}{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}}$ power:

$$x^{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} = \frac{9}{4} $$

$$  x = \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{ \frac{1}{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} }   $$

To see if this simplifies, let's take base-$10$ logarithms of both sides and see what happens:

$$  \log_{10} x \; = \; \log_{10} \left[ \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)^{ \frac{1}{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} } \right] $$

$$  \log_{10} x \; = \; \frac{1}{\log_{10} \frac{2}{3}} \cdot \log_{10} \left(\frac{9}{4}\right) \; = \; \frac{ \log_{10}\frac{9}{4} } { \log_{10} \frac{2}{3}  }$$

$$  \log_{10} x \; = \; \frac{ \log_{10} \left(  \frac{2}{3} \right)^{-2} } { \log_{10} \frac{2}{3}  } \; = \; \frac{ -2\log_{10}  \frac{2}{3} } { \log_{10} \frac{2}{3}  } \; = \; -2$$

Therefore, we have

$$x \; = \; 10^{-2} \; = \; \frac{1}{100} $$

As a safety check, let's see if this satisfies the original equation

$$ 4^{(\log x) + 1} \;\; - \;\; 6^{\log x} \;\; - \;\; 2 \times 3^{(2\log x) + 2} \;\; = \;\; 0    $$

Substituting $\log_{10} x = -2$ into the left side above gives

$$ 4^{-2 + 1} \;\; - \;\; 6^{-2} \;\; - \;\; 2 \times 3^{2(-2) + 2}  $$

$$ = \;\; 4^{-1} \;\; - \;\; 6^{-2} \;\; - \;\; 2 \times 3^{-2}   $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{1}{4} \;\; - \;\; \frac{1}{36} - \;\; \frac{2}{9} $$

$$ = \;\; \frac{9}{36} \;\; - \;\; \frac{1}{36} - \;\; \frac{8}{36} $$

$$ = \;\; 0 $$

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the *current* equation has no real solutions for $x$. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log$ can have different meanings,
let $\log=\log_a$ for some $a>1$ (most common values 
for $a$ are $\mathrm{e},10$ and $2$).

\begin{align} 
4^{\log_a(x) +1}-6^{\log_a(x)}-2\cdot3^{\log_a(x^2)+2}&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
4^1\cdot (2\cdot2)^{\log_a(x)}
-(2\cdot3)^{\log_a(x)}
-2\cdot3^2\cdot3^{2\log_a(x)}&=0
,\\
4\cdot 2^{\log_a(x)}\cdot 2^{\log_a(x)}
-2^{\log_a(x)}\cdot3^{\log_a(x)}
-18\cdot3^{\log_a(x)}\cdot3^{\log_a(x)}&=0
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Now, let's divide \eqref{2} by $2^{\log_a(x)}\cdot3^{\log_a(x)}$:

\begin{align} 
4\cdot\frac{2^{\log_a(x)}}{3^{\log_a(x)}}
-1
-18\cdot
\frac{3^{\log_a(x)}}{2^{\log_a(x)}}&=0
,\\
4\cdot\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\log_a(x)}
-1
-18\cdot\frac{1}{\left(\frac23\right)^{\log_a(x)}}
&=0
.
\end{align}

Let $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\log_a(x)}=t$. 
Then we have

\begin{align} 
4t-1
-18\cdot\frac{1}{t}
&=0
,\\
4\,t^2-t-18&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Quadratic equation \eqref{3}
has two solutions,
\begin{align} 
t_1&=\tfrac94
,\\
t_2&=-2
,
\end{align}

but we know that $t$ must be positive, so
the only option left is

\begin{align} 
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{\log_a(x)}
&=\frac94
=\left(\frac23\right)^{-2}
,\\
\log_a(x)&=-2
,\\
x&=a^{-2}
.
\end{align}

So if $\log$ means $\log_{10}$,
the answer would be $x=0.01.$