# What properties of exponents and logarithms is used here?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

In a solution to one of my assignment is given that:

$$4^{log_{16} n} = n^{log_{16} 4} = n^{\frac12}$$

I understand the 2nd part, that's simple, but how was the first part achieved?

Comment: FYI, I stumbled on the identity $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$ recently --- see my comments, and see "We now make use of the identity ..." in my answer, both at [Tricky logarithmic question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669425/tricky-logarithmic-question). See also [Name for a Logarithm Identity/Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854588/name-for-a-logarithm-identity-property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$y=4^{\log_{16}x}$$
$$\log_{16}y=\log_{16}(x^{\log_{16}4})$$
$$\log_{16}y=\log_{16}(x^{1/2})$$
$$y=x^{1/2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Indeed an important part is missing:

$4^{log_{16}n}= 16^{log_{16}4*log_{16}n} = n^{log_{16}4} $