# Logarithm proof problem: $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$

Tags: proof-writing, logarithms

I have been hit with a homework problem that I just have no idea how to approach. Any help from you all is very much appreciated. Here is the problem

Prove the equation: $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: You can use the change of base formula: $\log_b(x) = \frac{\ln x}{\ln b}$.

Comment: Should [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118125/constant-to-the-logn-equals-n-to-log-textconstant?noredirect=1&lq=1) be a duplicate of this question simply because it was posted after, or should it be the other way around due to the seemingly better content?  Perhaps, I would think, they should be duplicates of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10866/how-a-log-b-x-x-log-b-a?rq=1), which likely has the best quality of content.

Answer (score 13):

$\large{a^{\log_b c}=e^{\ln a \cdot\log_b c}= e^{\ln a\cdot\ln c/\ln b}}=c^{\ln a/\ln b}=c^{\log_b a}$.

Answer (score 7):

If you apply the logarithm with base $a$ to both sides you obtain,

$$\log_a a^{\log_b c} = \log_a c^{\log_b a}$$

$$\log_b c = \log_b a \log_a c$$

$$\frac{\log_b c}{\log_b a} = \log_a c$$

however this last equality is the change of base formula and hence is true.  Reversing the steps leads to the desired equality.

Comment: This is getting me closer to understanding it. This is actually for an algorithms class and the professor kinda sprung this one on us without teaching us a whole lot about logarithm properties. Haven't touched this stuff since clac >_<

Comment: The way to think of it is: you are trying to show that $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$, start at the change of base formula that relates $a$ and $c$ and work backwards to find your identity. This was super helpful, thank you @newToProgramming

Answer (score 3):

$a^{\log_b c} =c^{\log_b a}$

let $k= a^{log_b c}$

$\log k=\log( a^{\log_b c})$

$\log k=\log_b c \log a$

$\log k=\frac{\log c}{\log b} \log a$

$\log k=\frac{\log a}{\log b} \log c$

$\log k=\log_b a \log c$

$\log k=\log c^{\log_b a}$

substituting value of k

$\log a^{\log_b c}=\log c^{\log_b a} $

therefore

$a^{\log_b c} =c^{\log_b a}$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax reference.

Answer (score 1):

In log there is a property that :$x^{\large {\log _x  y}}=y$,$\log_x y=\log_w y\times\log_x w$
where $w$ can be any hold any possible value that is valid for a log base.
so $$a^{\large{\log_b c}}\implies a^{\large{\log_a c\times \log_b a}}$$
since $a^{\large{\log_a c}}=c$
so $$a^{\large{\log_a c\times \log_b a}}\implies c^{\large{\log_b a}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$, needs to be proven

let's assume LHS = x

$a^{\log_b c} = x$

take $log_a$ from both sides

$\log_a{(a^{\log_b c)}} = \log_a(x)$

$\log_b c = \log_a(x)$

change all base to $b$

$\log_b c = \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(a)}$

from this we extract $\log_b(a)$ which is $\log_b a = \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(c)}$

again right side can be written as $\log_c{x}$

so $\log_b a= \log_c{x}$

raise to the power of $c$

$c^{\log_b a}= c^{\log_c{x}}$

$c^{\log_b a}= x$

and we know what $x$ is so

$a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$

Answer (score 0):

Has no one hit upon the simplest way to do this, which is to take logarithms to the base $b$?

$\log_b(a^{\log_bc})=\log_bc\log_ba$,
$\log_b(c^{\log_ba})=\log_ba\log_bc$, done!