# How did my professor change this logarithm into the next one?

Tags: logarithms

Logarithms are a weak point for me and I'm curious how my professor went from the following logarithm to the next one. How are they equal?
$$ 3^{\log_4 n} = n^{\log_4 3} $$

And does that mean I can change $2^{\log_2{n}}$ to $n^{\log_2{2}}$?

Comment: See also:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2891737
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/320116
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1626298
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518266

Answer (score 5):

$x^y=e^{y\ln x}$  and $\log_{x}y = \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$.  Hence $$3^{\log_4n}=e^{\ln 3\frac{\ln n}{\ln 4}}=e^{\ln n\frac{\ln 3}{\ln 4}}=n^{\log_43}$$

Your proposed change is fine, although you don't really need it; $2^{\log_2n}=n$, since the exponentiation and logarithm cancel, being to the same base.

Comment: Well, the change he made makes that easy to see: $2^{\log_2 n}=n^{\log_2 2}=n^1=n$.

Comment: I disagree; $2\times \frac{1}{2}\times x=x$ is just as easy to see as $x\times 2\times \frac{1}{2}=x$.