# How is $2^{\log_4 n}= n^{\log _42}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I saw in a notebook the following: $2^{\log_4 n}= n^{\log _42}(=\sqrt n)$, but I never saw this before and I can't find it in any log rules, is it right? and if so how did they do it?

BTW, if we take $\log_2$ of both sides we get: $${\log_4 n} = {\log _42}\log_2 n= \frac 1 2 \log_2 n$$ which makes both sides look even more different.

EDIT: OK, never mind. I found that rule: [image]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities

Funny they don't mention it everywhere...

Comment: Don't take $\log_2$ but take $\log_4$ for clarity.

Comment: The idea is to write everything as a power of,or log to, the same base.Here the base to choose is 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the logarithm in base $4$:
\begin{align}
&\mathrm{(LHS)} & \log_4(2^{\log_4n})=(\log_4n)(\log_42) \\
&\mathrm{(RHS)} & \log_4(n^{\log_42})=(\log_42)(\log_4n)
\end{align}
Since the logarithms are equal, the numbers are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, log rule:  $\color{red}{\log_{a^n}(b)=\frac 1n\log_a(b)}$ hence, simplifying LHS & RHS as follows

$$LHS=2^{\log_4n}=2^{\log_{2^2}n}=2^{\frac{1}{2}\log_2n}=2^{\log_2n^{1/2}}=n^{1/2}=\color{blue}{\sqrt n}$$
$$RHS=n^{\log_42}=n^{\log_{2^2}2}=n^{\frac{1}{2}\log_22}=n^{\frac 12}=\color{blue}{\sqrt n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try rewriting
$$2^{\log_4 n}$$
as
$$\bigg(4^{\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)^{\log_4 n}$$

Answer (score 0):

They aren't different. $\log_4(2)=\frac12$ because $4^{1/2}=2$.

Answer (score 0):

The left side is equivalent to $$2^{\frac{log(n)}{log(4)}}$$
       and the right side is equivalent to $$n^{\frac{log(2)}{log(4)}}$$

The equation is therefore true, when $2^{log(n)}=n^{log(2)}$

Logarithming both sides gives $log(n)log(2)=log(2)log(n)$, so the given equation
is actually true. Because of $\frac{log(2)}{log(4)}=\frac{1}{2}$, the result is
$\sqrt{n}$ in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

...or use the property of the natural logarithm:

$$
t = 2^{\log_2 t} = 2^{\frac{\ln t}{\ln 2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In general we have:

$\forall a > 1, \ \forall b > 1, \ \log_a n = \log_a b \ \cdot \ \log_b n$

Proof:

$\log_a n = \frac{\ln n}{\ln a} = \frac{\ln n}{\ln a} \ \cdot \ \frac{\ln b}{\ln b} = \frac{\ln b}{\ln a} \ \cdot \ \frac{\ln n}{\ln b} = \log_a b \ \cdot \ \log_b n$

Therefore we have:

$\mathrm{2}^{\log_4 n} = \mathrm{2}^{\log_4 2 \ \cdot \ \log_2 n} = \mathrm{2}^{\log_2 n \ \cdot \ \log_4 2} = n^{\log_4 2}$