# Prove that $a^{\ln{(b)}} = b^{\ln{(a)}}$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

> Prove that $a^{\ln{(b)}} = b^{\ln{(a)}}$ for any values of $a$ and $b$
>   that are positive and different from 1.

My book says the solution is:
\begin{align*}
\log_a(a^{\ln(b)})=\log_a(b^{\ln(a)}) 
&\Leftrightarrow \ln(b) \cdot \log_a{a} = \ln(a)\cdot \log_a(b) \\
&\Leftrightarrow \frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)} = \log_ab \\
&\Leftrightarrow \log_ab = \log_ab
\end{align*}

I can understand this solution and I understand that since this is a logarithm, all the input values (a and b) must be positive. What I don't understand is how this proves that a and b have to be different from one. Can anyone explain that to me?

Thanks

Comment: They don't have to be different from 1. If you check, subbing 1 for either constant works. It's just not interesting.

Comment: The "solution" doesn't prove the claim for $a=b=1$, true. The problematic step is when it takes $\log_a$ both sides when $\log_a$ cannot be defined for $a=1$.

Comment: @user160738 Why not?

Comment: Your book gives a too complicated solution. Instead, take ln of both sides. Thus there is no problem with $a=1$ and $b=1.$

Comment: @AliceIsDead $\log_a (x)$ is defined as the inverse function of $a^x$, but when $a=1$ the function $a^x$ is identically $1$, so it is far from being bijective. So inverse cannot exist

Comment: @JeanMarie Would $a = b$ be correct?

Comment: What it has done, it has used the fact that $\log_{a} (b) = \frac{log_{c}(a)}{\log_{c} (b)}$ (for any positive $a,b,c$). For an easier proof you can do this $a^{\ln (b)} = e^{\ln(a) \ln(b)}$, and the same for the right side.

Comment: The issue does not exist $1^{\ln(1)}=1^0=1$ is perfectly defined !

Comment: @AliceIs Dead we don't have to assume $a=b$. It is true for any $a,b>0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logarithm proof problem: $a^{\log_b c} = c^{\log_b a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320116/logarithm-proof-problem-a-log-b-c-c-log-b-a)

Comment: Take log both sides, it is done to any base, it is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly for positive $a,b$ one has
$$
\log(a)\log(b)=\log(b)\log(a).
$$
Using "the $x\log(y)=\log(y^x)$-property" of logarithms you have that
$$
\log(b^{\log(a)})=\log(a^{\log(b)}).
$$
As the logarithm is an injective function this implies
$$
b^{\log(a)}=a^{\log(b)}.
$$
There is no need to assume that $a\neq1$ or $b\neq1$, it is just that that case is obvious.

Answer (score 8):

This is anyway a complicated solution. Just use the *definition* of $x^y$ for $x>0$:
$$\begin{cases}
a^{\ln b}=\mathrm e^{\ln b\,\ln a}, \\
b^ {\ln a}=\mathrm e^{\ln a\,\ln b}.
\end{cases}$$