# How to simplify this formula: $ x^{\ln \left( 3 \right)}-3^{\ln \left( x \right)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Here's the formula: $$ x^{\ln \left( 3 \right)}-3^{\ln \left( x \right)}$$

I know it's equal to $0$ because I've tried different values for $x$, but how do I solve it, how do I simplify it to $0$?

Comment: Go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320116/logarithm-proof-problem-a-log-b-c-c-log-b-a and substitue $b = e$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First
$$
x^{\ln(3)}=e^{\ln(3)\ln(x)}
$$
And
$$
3^{\ln(x)}=e^{\ln(x)\ln(3)}
$$

So yes it values $0$.

Comment: it's funny that I can solve harder formulas but the most simple I can not. Any tips on how to overcome that ? Practice or memorize? ;)

Comment: Practice is better IMO.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: For any positive real number $r$, $r=e^{\ln (r)}$. Apply this now to $r=x$ and $r=3$.

Comment: Ah, I see three of us have posted almost simultaneously!

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @user32073, I'm afraid I don't understand your comment.

Comment: what is the problem about the posts being posted almost simultaneously?

Comment: @user32073, oh, there's no problem, I was just acknowledging that three of us had almost the exact same idea -- a case of great minds thinking alike....

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use the fact that $a^x=e^{x\ln a}$ for $a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for positive values of $x$,$$ x^{\ln \left( 3 \right)}=3^{\ln \left( x \right)}= e^{ln(3).ln(x)}$$

Therefore, $$ x^{\ln \left( 3 \right)}-3^{\ln \left( x \right)}=0$$

Comment: You are initially assuming the answer equals $0$. Why?

Comment: @idk Because making an assumption is a good first step of proving statements (especially by contra-diction). For example, we may not know if $\sqrt 2$ is rational, or irrational. So, we *assume* $\sqrt 2 = p/q$ and where does this lead us?

Comment: @user477343 What you are believing is incorrect. Here, you have to prove $a-b=0$, and the answer is assuming $a-b=0$ to prove $a-b=0$. In the case of $\sqrt 2$, you are assuming the OPPOSITE of what is correct to prove what is correct.

Comment: @idk ahhh I see... thank you for letting me know :)